# How to change MySQL 5.6.22 Data Directory using Workbench GUI?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to change the default Data Directory path in MySQL 5.6.22
Is there any way to change using workbench / MySQL tools.
I am using Window 7 x64 Bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the management section of workbench there's the editor for the config file. Use that to set the data dir:

[image]

Comment: The editor is not in the management section but in the instance section, under "Options file".

Comment: Well, it's a name clash. "Management" appears twice, as the heading of the tab view and as the heading of the section group. Meanwhile the tab heading has been renamed to "Adminstration".

Answer (score 2):

i got the same problem, only to discover the SIMPLE solution after hours of working:

1.) stop mysql on workbench
2.) change the direcotry
3.) right click on the  mysql service
4.) properties
5.) logon tab
6.) select Local System Account radio button
7.) restart mysql on workbench
8.) tadaaa!

Comment: 2.1 Copy data directory (including mysql subdir) from original mysql location to desired location.

Comment: As an addition to this, the problem is that the 'Network Service' account that the mysql service is running under doesn't have full control of the new data folder. You can also change the permissions on the directory instead of changing the account.